# Get the linked workitem in a release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up a branch policy for the main branch that requires pull requests and linked workitems.

A build is configured as part of the branch policy.

Once the build for the merge is completed a release pipeline picks up the artifact. The release has "Pull request deployment" activated in the "Pre-deployment conditions"

In the release pipeline I need the information about the linked workitem. Is there a way to get it?

**EDIT**

At the end I could use the easy way and rely on the branch name that in our team conventions contains the pbi

The answer is still a good one. So I keep the question here

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible, though a little awkward. Steps would be as follows:

1. Get the Build ID associated with the artifact using the [Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) variable
2. Use the [Get Build Work Items Refs API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-work-items-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the list of work items linked to the PR build